# Download json file with axios via s3 presigned_url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

The scenario is simple. The json sent by the lambda aws exceeds the 10MB payload limit.
Is it a good practice to use a presigned_url to return this huge json and get the response by axios?

Unfortunately I receive this error. The link I received is valid, I can display the json on my browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-perfect-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-super-key?AWSAccessKeyId=XXX&Signature=XXX&x-amz-security-token=XXX&Expires=XXX' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Should I add a parameter to my axios method?

My lambda

```
import json, boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    key = body["key"]
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                         Params={'Bucket': "my-perfect-bucket",
                                                 'Key': key},                     # json file 
                                         ExpiresIn=300,
                                         HttpMethod='GET')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response, default=str)
    }
```

My axios method:

```
this.$axios
    .post(`/my-cool-api/get`, {
        key: this.key
    })
    .then(r => {
        this.$axios
            .get(r.data)
            .then(json => {
                this.mySuperData = json.data
            })
    })
```

Comment: did you set a cors policy on that s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

add this to your s3 bucket -> permissions -> cors