# Amazon S3 bucket gives AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am getting an Access Denied error while getting a list of available items in my S3 Bucket. I am using the correct identityPoolId, bucket name, and region while making a request. My bucket is also set to public access. [image]
Here is my cross-origin resource sharing JSON

```
    [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Here is my error message
[image]

I am new to S3 storage on AWS. what I might be doing wrong here?
**updated CORS**
[image]

**Update 2**
I am having these access attached to the user making the request
[image]

Comment: can youtry the policy given in this answer, copy exactly as it is, as in your json policy the indentation is misplaced. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996661/13126651, did it help?, here is the reference example from docs too https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra that did not help. It still gives the same error

Comment: I have updated the JSON in the question. the indentation disturbs here but it is correct

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I even followed the one from the docs too but still it gives error

Comment: @JatinMehrotra this is not the issue regarding the configuration of CORS, I think. It looks some other issues

Comment: yes its probably cognito issue, which i not used to.

Comment: Could you please specify some of the reference links that I could follow to find the issue? Thanks

Comment: the identity pools look fine . I can't fine anything there.